# Prolog syntax error: operator expected

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

I was studying the Prolog, and met with the "syntax error: operator expected" for the following code:

```
odd_list(X,Y):-process_list(X,Y,1).
process_list(X,[N1|Y],N):-N1 is 2*N-1,N1 < X,N2 is N+1,process_list(X,Y,N2).
process_list(X,[],N):-2*N-1>=X.
```

That's all the code I wrote. What's the problem? I found some solutions saying that there are unexpected white spaces in the functors or arguments, but I think I do not include any white space in the above-mentioned places.
Thank you all for helping me!!!

**Remark:** I find that when I name the source code as "Test1.pl", I get this error. But when I name it as "test1.pl", there is no error. Does it mean that the file name cannot start with an upper case letter?

Comment: How are you loading your source code?

Comment: You need to show how you load it: if I type at the interactive prompt `?- [test].` then it works, if the source is in a file `test.pl`.

Comment: Uppercase starting symbols are **variables**. I guess you used `?- [Test1]`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. I used [Test1]. Now I modify it and it's solved. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason for this problem. I used the file name 'Test1'. But Prolog does not support upper case letter in the file name. I modified the file name to 'test1' and it works now.